# Feed importer: field collection processor settings

Tags: feeds, users, entities, importing-exporting

I'm trying to import field collection to profile2.

I do not understand where to get in the Field Collection Processor information for the "Field/property name of Host entity GUID" and "Identifier field name" settings to fill in the text box?

Please see the image below.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: This blog post explains those two fields
http://doreydesigngroup.com/blog/drupal-field-collection-feeds-import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work!

**Settings for Field collection processor**

Do not update existing field collection item

Field name: (The machine-readable name of the field collection)

Host entity type: Profile

Is field: unchecked (FALSE)

Field/property name of Host entity GUID: pid

Identifier field name: pid

**Mapping for Field collection processor**

pid => Host Entity GUID

(and my other fields of course)

**Note:**

pid is the Profile ID.